# selecting a substring with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am trying to parse a html document using javascript, its getting late and I am struggling a bit with the regex's.

I have a document that contains the following:

```
<table>
{% for field in fields %}
<tr><td>{{field.label}}</td><td>{{field.value}}</td></tr>                   
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Now i want to somehow select everything between {% for field in fields %} and {% endfor %} so that I can insert some fake figure into the label and value fields. Then I want to duplicate this section a few times so that it creates the wanted dummy output. Does anyone know an easy way to select everything between the for and endfor loop tags?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to create your own version of [Templates](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/)?

Comment: You can do this with a fairly simple regex (make sure it can handle the newlines) as long as you don't nest those tags.

Comment: I dont think the jquery templates will work because I dont know the markup of that section in advance. In the example posted the two variables are inside a table row but it could just as easily be inside a div etc. Okay thanks for the confirmation that it can easily be done with regex, will figure it out after some sleep. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var regex = /(?:{% for field in fields %})([\s\S]*?)(?:{% endfor %})/gim;

var contents = regex.exec(test)[1];
```

Brief explanation of regex...

`(?:{% for field in fields %})` : Non capturing group (`?:`) to match opening "tag"

`([\s\S]*?)` : `[\s\S]` matches any character in JS regex (including newline) `*` matches 0 or more instances of the preceeding character class `?` makes the match lazy (so in this example it won't potentially eat up a closing tag)

`(?:{% endfor %})` : Non capturing group (`?:`) to match closing "tag"

Flags `gim` - *global* (ie match all in the input string) / *case insensitive* / *multiline*

Comment: kinda greedy... this will match the first `{% for...` tag, then  backtrack from the end of the document to the last occurrence of `{% endfor %}` and capture all the tags in between (which would JUST FINE if there was only one `for` tag in the document)...

Comment: Thanks El! By making it use lazy matching ((\S|\s)*?) it also works on documents with more than one for loop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Code Yeah true, I'll update. I only tested it quickly in JSFiddle and hadn't got round to doing a test with multiple captures. Should have made it lazy anyway though... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp groups ($1, $2, $3) for this:

```
var html = '{% for field in fields %}'
+ '<tr><td>{{field.label}}</td><td>{{field.value}}'
+ '</td></tr>'
+ '{% endfor %}';
var pattern = /({% for field in fields %})((.|\n)*)({% endfor %})/gi;

pattern.test(html);
var forText = RegExp.$2;
newForText = forText.replace(/{{field.label}}/gi, 'My Label').replace(/{{field.value}}/gi, 'My Value');
console.log('<table>' + newForText + '</table>');
```